# Android AVD screen temporarily freezing up while calling JSON for log-in

Tags: android, json, authentication, emulation, freeze

I have a log-in screen that I'm using for my application. It calls JSON to verify if the username/password is correct, if so, it signs them in and they are directed to the main menu. However, since it takes about 10-15 seconds to log in, I added a very simple "Progress Bar" widget to display that it is, in fact, signing in (so the user isn't confused). However, whenever I test it on the emulator and log in, the log-in screen seems to freeze and then after the 10-15 seconds it logs in just fine, but the Progress Bar never displayed because the AVD screen is freezing up. I have it to set itself to visible when the JSON call is made. If I go back to the log-in screen after I am logged in successfully, the progress bar is there and showing up just fine.

Any tips on a way to remedy this? Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you performing your login request on the main thread? If yes, consider using AsyncTask and check this -> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

If no, could you give some more details, probably with a snippet of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use `AsyncTask` for performing long-time taking operations. And to notify user use `ProgressBar` or `AlertDialog` or any other notifier, which fits your needs.

You should think about slow networks (2G, 3G) and possible data-rates limits, whatever, what can slow operation.

Your code should be handling long-time taking operations in another than UI thread (which is basically what `Activity` is, the UI thread).

To understand use and purpose of `AsyncTask` consider reading following links.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy, I'm going to give these things a look-over now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this, if you logging-in in onCreate method for example.

```
  public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private static ProgressDialog pd = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
       YourActivity.this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this,
                        "Logging-in..", "Please wait...", true, false);
       new DownloadTask().execute(your parameters);
    }

     private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<param, param, param> {
        protected param doInBackground(param... params) {
                       //logging-in     
                    }
        protected void onPostExecute(your_result) {
                   if (YourActivity.this.pd != null) {
                      YourActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
                   }
                }
     }
  }
```